# Tried to create sorting program, but isn't working as expected

Tags: c

The following code is written for sorting array.
Here the program gives unexpected output results.
The error should be in line 10-19.

```
#include<stdio.h>   //Sorting array program
int main()
{
    int arr[20],i,j,n,temp;
    printf("Enter number of elements  : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements of the array : ");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<arr[i];j++)
            if (arr[i+1]<arr[i])
            {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
    }
    printf("\nThe sorted list is : \n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n arr[%d] : %d",i,arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output ::
         Enter number of elements  : 4

```
     Enter the elements of the array : 5
     3
     2
     1

     The sorted list is : 

      arr[0] : 3
      arr[1] : 2
      arr[2] : 1
      arr[3] : -16777216
      Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.161 s
      Press ENTER to continue.
```

Comment: Smells like an "index out of bounds" error.

Comment: Which sorting algorithm is this? I have a doubt on inner for loop.

Comment: `j<arr[i]` ??..

Comment: I tried to create my own. its more like bubble sortt+ insertion sort @Gaurav

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Thankyou for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your program likes this and you'll find out what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>   //Sorting array program
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[20], i, j, n, temp;
  printf("Enter number of elements  : ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\nEnter the elements of the array : ");

  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
  {                                       // <<< line added
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++)
    {
      assert(j < n);                      // <<< line added
      assert(i + 1 < n);                  // <<< line added

      if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i])
      {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }                                     // <<< line added
  }

  printf("\nThe sorted list is : \n");

  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    printf("\n arr[%d] : %d", i, arr[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Read about `assert` **[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm)**.

But anyway the algorithm looks fishy to me anyway:

This line is particularly suspicious:

```
for (j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++)
```

Comment: 0: main: Assertion `i + 1 < n' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @Shushrut exactly, that's the point: you are accessing one element beyond the last element of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>   //Sorting array program

int main()
{
    int arr[20], i, j, n, temp;

    printf("Enter number of elements  : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements of the array : ");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
            if (arr[i]<arr[j])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
    }
    printf("\nThe sorted list is : \n");
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
         printf("\n arr[%d] : %d", i, arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```